# Правильно ли подчеркнуты члены предложнения?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Служебные части речи *"не","в"* членами предложения не являются. *«Что»* - союз, а не союзное слово, следовательно не член предложения.

По поводу подлежащего. Оно выражено словосочетанием *"участь похода"*  (имя в именительном падеже + имя в родительном падеже).

Правильно?

Answer (score 2):

> *…я не подозревал*

Я бы разбирал это предложение так:

***я*** —  подлежащее;

***не подозревал*** — сказуемое (частица входит в состав сказуемого);

> *...что участь похода решалась в эту минуту.*

Здесь:

***участь***  — подлежащее;

***похода***  — несогласованное определение, осложнённое свойствами дополнения;

***решалась***  — сказуемое;

***в эту минуту*** — обстоятельство времени (подчеркнуть штрихпунктирной линией).

Comment: slava1947,полностью согласен с вашим разбором, только следовало бы сказать,что при разборе допустимо не подчеркивать смысловые частицы. Иначе автор может счесть, что у него ошибк

Comment: А обстоятельство разве может быть выражено существительным с местоимением? Ладно сущ. с предлогом, но с местоимением...

Comment: _Daisy: А обстоятельство разве может быть выражено существительным с местоимением?_ === Конечно может. И в Вашем предложении только так, по-моему, и нужно квалифицировать сочетание "в эту минуту". Вряд ли на вопрос "когда  решалась (участь похода)?" возможен ответ "в минуту". Правильно: "в эту минуту" (обстоятельство, выраженное цельным словосочетанием).

Comment: А почему тогда подлежащее не может быть выражено цельным словосочетанием "участь похода"?